# How does XPathSelectElement work? C#

Tags: c#, xml

I ran into the following problem. I have an xml-file like this:

```
<Source Name ="ClassificationManager">
  <Table Name ="PositiveRegex">
    <Row>
      <Field Name="RegexPattern">^.*$</Field>
      <Field Name="Fraction">5.1</Field>
      <Field Name="ClassificationTypeNumber">1</Field>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Field Name="RegexPattern">^.*$</Field>
      <Field Name="Fraction">0.1</Field>
      <Field Name="ClassificationTypeNumber">2</Field>
    </Row>
  </Table>

  <Table Name ="NegativeRegex">
    <Row>
      <Field Name="RegexPattern">^.*$</Field>
      <Field Name="ClassificationTypeNumber">1</Field>
    </Row>
    <Row>
      <Field Name="RegexPattern">^.*$</Field>
      <Field Name="ClassificationTypeNumber">2</Field>
    </Row>
  </Table>

</Source>
```

and C# program:

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Repository.xml");

    XElement element = doc.XPathSelectElement(@"//Source[@Name='ClassificationManager']/Table[@Name='NegativeRegex']");

    foreach (var xmlRow in element.Elements("Row"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xmlRow.XPathSelectElement(@"//Field[@Name='ClassificationTypeNumber']").Value);
    }
```

The output is `1, 1` but not `1, 2` as I want it to be. What's wrong? How to modify the C# code to get what I need?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine(xmlRow.XPathSelectElement(@"//Field[@Name='ClassificationTypeNumber']").Value);
```

has to be:

```
Console.WriteLine(xmlRow.XPathSelectElement(@"/Field[@Name='ClassificationTypeNumber']").Value);
```

`//` selects from the root, not the current element.

Comment: You are almost right. You Just need to put a dot before slash.